# Catching Error in textbox before sending to SQL server

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, sql-server-2012

I'm making a shopping cart website ASP.NET. I have a page to manage my products. When I click on the button `Submit` I want to announce a message if the user forgets to enter data into `TextBox` (Ex: `ProductName`,`Price`).

If all `TextBox` are not null it will be inserted to my database. I use SQL Server and the Entity Framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the required attribute:

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" name="product" required />
  <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. i did it